# SharePoint Calendar view with Query String Filter

Tags: 2013, filter, sharepoint-calendar, query-string, ootb

I need to create two custom columns inside SharePoint Calendar List and I need to apply Filtering to calendar view with regards to custom columns for the users.

I need to apply the same using default Calendar App and Option available with me is SharePoint Designer.

So if any body has any idea or implemented the same, please help me...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi,

I'm not sure I get what you want to do: do you need to filter the calendar based on users' properties ?

Comment: I want to filter based on Query String and not based on user Properties.

Comment: As Calendar View does not support OOTB filters connection, it seems you'll need to develop a custom view then connect it to a Query String Filter Web Part

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you need, then you can do the following using OOTB feature from UI:

1. Create your two custom columns
2. Modify the default view for the calendar
3. Add two filters based on your custom columns

Comment: In question i have mentioned that i need filtering based on query string and not default filtering.. So your answer does not help me up...

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using parameterbinding on your calender view:

- Open the page in SharePoint designer and edit your pages that contains the calender webpart.

  - Add two parameterbindings for your columns like:`<ParameterBinding Name="mycustomcol1" />`
  - Save your page.
  - Go to SharePoint, edit the page
  - Add query string filter webpart
  - Connect the filter webpart to your calender webpart and use the option, get parameter from.
  - Do this for you other columns as well
  - Then open the webpart properties of your calender webpart and edit the view
  - Use you parameters to filter your view. It can be used like {mycustomcol1}

Comment: Calendar list view webpart does not take connection from query string filter webpart...
I have tried that Approach..