# SharePoint calendar view with query string filter in foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I  have a calendar view, I have to display the contents in view based on the value of query string in the url. How can I achieve this in SharePoint foundation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use OOTB filter Web part.

Insert Query string Url filter web part on the same page where you have calender view.

[image]

Click on "Open the tool pane"

[image]

Enter Query string parameter name and default Value

[image].

And Create connection

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but in SharePoint foundation  Query string Url filter web part is not supportive.  Is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: Yeah I jsut checked it,Connection cannot be made with calendar view.

Comment: Please check this, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179586/sharepoint-calendar-view-with-query-string-filter

Comment: I have checked it, it is working for list view but not working for the calendar view.

Comment: Is there any other way that i can filter the calendar view based on query string value.

Comment: Need to create Custom Visual webpart.

Comment: So custom calendar webpart has to be created.  How to create my own custom calendar?

Comment: Refer following link https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSSharePointCustomCalendar-0e922479